# Load multiple locale specific properties files in internationalization with resource bundle in java

Tags: java, properties, locale, resourcebundle

I have four properties files

1. Application.properties
2. Application_fr_FR.properties
3. Database.properties
4. Database_fr_FR.properties

So now I need internationalization in multiple programs, so now I need to load multiple properties files and get the key-value pair of values from properties files specific to a locale. For that I have a ResourceBundleService.java

```
public class ResourceBundleService {
    private static String language;
    private static String country;
    private static Locale currentLocale;
    static ResourceBundle labels;
    static {
        labels = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle("uday.properties.Application");
        labels = append(Database.properties");
        //** how to append existing resource bundle with new properties file?
    }

    public static String getLabel(String resourceIndex, Locale locale) {
        return labels.getString(resourceIndex);
        //How to get locale specific messages??
    }
}
```

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale)` each time  in `getLabel`. ResourceBundle maintains an internal cache so it wont load all props files each time:

```
public static String getLabel(String resourceIndex, Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle b1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("uday.properties.Application", locale);
    if (b1.contains(resourceIndex)) {
       return b1.getString(resourceIndex);
    }
    ResourceBundle b2 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("uday.properties.Database", locale);
    return b2.getString(resourceIndex);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for the information on internal cache but how do i call multiple properties files??????

Comment: Oh thank you for the information on internal cache but how do i call multiple properties files??????

Comment: I doubt theres a better solution than trying to find in Application first and if not found in Database, see update

Answer (score 0):

For the time being use Application_fr.properties; *les Canadiens* will be thankful. With `Locale.setDefault(availableLocale)` elect an available locale. The root locale properties, Application.properties, should also contain the language keys. You could copy the French ones. In that case you need not set the default locale.

Comment: How do I load Database.properties and Application.properties at the same time so that I can one access point for ResourceBundle??

Comment: @EvgenlyDorofeev answered that. Do not try to use an additional Map for all, as the bundles are already optimized. A `getLabel(String rIx, Locale, ResourceBundle... bundles)` might have its uses too.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check this implementation on [github](https://github.com/dueni/faces-ext/tree/master/resourcebundle) it works really nice. It requires the following function naming convention:

> MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle is an abstract base implementation to allow to combine a ResourceBundle from multiple properties files whereas these properties files must end with the same name - the base-name for these combined ResourceBundle.

If you'll use it at the first you need to implement abstract class `MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle` as below:

```
import ch.dueni.util.MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle;

public class CombinedResources extends MultiplePropertiesResourceBundle {

    public  CombinedResources() {
        super("package_with_bundles");
    }

}
```

then you should implement empty class which extends out `CombinedResources`:

```
public class CombinedResources_en extends CombinedResources {}
```

and so on for other languages. After that you can use your bundle as below:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("CombinedResources");
```

This bundle will be use all properties files inside `package_with_bundles`. For more information just look inside github repo.